# HttpsURLConnection returns --> java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address

Tags: java, android, https, http-post, httpsurlconnection

I useing `HttpsURLConnection` to do a POST request, sometimes I get the following error back `java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address`
but sometimes it works fine, any idea on how to prevent this.

```
HttpsURLConnection myConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL( tURL ).openConnection();
myConnection.setRequestMethod( "POST" );

myConnection.setRequestProperty("info", "ok");
myConnection.setRequestProperty("type", "car");
myConnection.setRequestProperty("type", tRequestString);
myConnection.setDoOutput(true);

//Adding Post Data
OutputStream outputStream = myConnection.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(post_data.getBytes());
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();

myConnection.setConnectTimeout( 100000 );
myConnection.setReadTimeout( 100000 );
myConnection.connect();
```

tURL

```
https://my.url.com/folder/folder2/fileee.cgi
```

Comment: i suppose depends on what contains `tURL`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I updated the question to include the value of tURL

Comment: 99% you have to post the real url, you might are doing something wrong in the url (we just need the path and query, hide the domain name for security reason)

Comment: Do not close() the output stream.

Comment: `myConnection.setConnectTimeout( 100000 );` Pretty late you set timeout.

Comment: `myConnection.connect();` Connect? You already posted your stuff. How could that be done without a connection?